# Telling journalctl to show all but a certain facility

Tags: systemd-journald, dhcpd

I'm trying to get rid of dhcpd spam in my journal.

Using `rsyslog.conf` and `dhcpd.conf` I have been able to [keep it out](https://lists.isc.org/pipermail/dhcp-users/2012-March/015214.html) of `/var/log/syslog` and put it in `/var/log/dhcpd.log` which is great.

However, `journalctl` will still show the dhcpd spam.

How do I instruct journalctl to use an "everything-but-X" filter?

I don't want to type

```
$ journalctl --facility=kern,user,mail,....,local7
```

But invert the logic to something like:

```
$ journalctl --facility=!local7
```

But that latter syntax is incorrect. Is there a way to achieve this? Or else, filter on `!dhcpd` or something?

Comment: AFAIK it doesn't support negation ... However, you can filter with e.g. `... | grep -v "word" | less`

Comment: @raffa Thank you. Once piped through another program, the log loses all colour encodings. So no longer red errors, yellow warnings. I need the option in systemctl itself.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `journalctl` doesn't seem to support that kind of excluding output by negating a certain facility.

Possible workarounds are:

- Using `grep` with the [`-v, --invert-match`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/grep.1.html#options) option like so:

  ```
  journalctl | grep --line-buffered -v 'pattern'
  ```
- Using `grep` with [`ccze`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/ccze.1.html)(*needs install*) log colorizer for color coded output like so:

  ```
  journalctl | grep --line-buffered -v 'pattern' | ccze -A
  ```
- Using `journalctl` builtin [`-g, --grep=`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/journalctl.1.html#options) option with [PCRE2](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man3/pcre2pattern.3.html) regular expressions pattern to filter entries by the message field like so:

  ```
  journalctl --grep='pattern'
  ```

  This one will be tricky to negate a string, but your best bet might be to include negative [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).